# WARN driver.MahoutDriver: Unable to add class: org.apache.mahout.classifier.bayes.PrepareTwentyNewsgroups

Tags: hadoop, mahout

I'm new with Hadoop and Mahout. First, I ran the easy example of Bayes classifier offered by Mahout. I want to get the Bayes train input data set, so I ran the command below:

```
mahout org.apache.mahout.classifier.bayes.PrepareTwentyNewsgroups

-p /Examples/20news-bydate-train

-o /Examples/bayes-train-input

-a org.apache.mahout.vectorizer.DefaultAnalyzer

-c UTF-8
```

but the outcome is

> [image]

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

From Mahout version 0.6, CLI APIs such as PrepareTwentyNewsgroups, trainclassifier，testclassifier, etc. is deprecated, and you can run some shell scripts examples from examples/bin directory, e.g. running examples/bin/classify-20newsgroups.sh.

One possible solution for this problem is to regress to version 0.6.

Answer (score 0):

as it is written:

```
 MAHOUT_LOCAL is not set
```

and therefore it is not possible to find `PrepareTwentyNewsGroups` class. According to your system, set up environment variable MAHOUT_LOCAL, e.g.:

```
  MAHOUT_LOCAL=/usr/local/lib/mahout
  export MAHOUT_LOCAL
```

(put those lines into your .bash_profile file, or just into your shell to try and try if it is working)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, according to http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/mahout/trunk/bin/mahout :

> MAHOUT_LOCAL : set to anything other than an empty string to force mahout to run locally even if HADOOP_CONF_DIR and HADOOP_HOME are set

You only have to set MAHOUT_LOCAL if you want to run mahout locally.
If you want to run it on a hadoop cluster, just set HADOOP_HOME and HADOOP_CONF_DIR.